# Rearrange vector every nth column

Tags: matlab, vector

Let's say I have a vector:

```
A=[1 2 3 6 7 8 11 12 13]
```

and I'm trying to achieve final output like:

```
[1 6 11 2 7 12 3 8 13]
```

Where the vector is rearranged to front every nth column, in this case, 3rd. Using indexing will work, but it requires a loop, which I'm trying to avoid. Any idea how to do it in a vectorized way? Thanks!

```
nth=3;
for i=1:nth:size(A,2)
    A_(:,nth)= A(:,i:nth:end)
end
```

Comment: Assuming the length of `A` is divisible by 3 then `reshape(reshape(A,3,[]).',1,[])` should work.

Comment: @jodag, to generalize it to the nth column as in the question, just replace the `3` with `n`

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion that @jodag posted in the comments works totally fine. Alternatively, this should also do the job... but the constraint is the same, `A` must be divisible by `nth`:

```
nth = 3;
A = [1 2 3 6 7 8 11 12 13];
A_len = numel(A);
A_div = floor(A_len / nth);

seq = repmat(1:nth:A_len,1,A_div);
inc = sort(repmat(0:nth-1,1,A_div));

A = A(seq + inc)
```

Output:

```
A =
     1     6    11     2     7    12     3     8    13
```